# Zookeeper - Error the current epoch, is older than the last zxid

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am using a zookeeper ensemble of 3 nodes running 3.4.13. Sometimes after reboot of machine zookeeper is not starting in one of the node and I am seeing the below errors in logs

```
2019-08-19 04:18:36,906 [myid:2] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeer@692] - Unable to load database on disk
java.io.IOException: The current epoch, 7, is older than the last zxid, 34359738370
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:674)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:635)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:170)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:114)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
2019-08-19 04:18:36,908 [myid:2] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@92] - Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to run quorum server
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:693)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:635)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:170)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:114)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The current epoch, 7, is older than the last zxid, 34359738370
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:674)
... 4 more----
```

I have seen [ZOOKEEPER-2354](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2354) and the symptoms look similar.

```
support@platform2:/var/lib/zookeeper/version-2$ sudo cat acceptedEpoch
8support@platform2:/var/lib/zookeeper/version-2$ sudo cat currentEpoch
7support@platform2:/var/lib/zookeeper/version-2$ sudo cat currentEpoch.tmp
8support@platform2
```

The above issue states the issue is fixed in 3.4.6 but I am observing the same in 3.4.13.

Can someone let me know how can I recover the zookeeper node from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed in [zookeeper mailing thread](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/The-current-epoch-7-is-older-than-the-last-zxid-8589935882-td7584265.html). Relevant quote from that thread

> With the other two zookeeper servers running I stopped the zookeeper
>   in the  broken node and the deleted all the contents inside 
>   `/var/lib/zookeeper/version-2` and started the zookeeper back on the
>   node. It is running fine now and got all the data from the other
>   servers.

Comment: this is also require Kafka to be restarted (stop/start). so make sure you do the following sequence 1. stop kafka before zookeeper, 2. stop zookeeper 3. rename version-2 to be backup-version-2 (backup) 4. delete version-2 file 5. start all zookeeper 6. start Kafka